# External Monitor (Lenovo) doesn't wake up after lock screen wake

Tags: multiple-monitors, suspend, external-monitor

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and my screen locks, after some time goes by my external monitor (Lenovo) seems to fall into a deep sleep, from which it doesn't wake, when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and type my password into my lock screen.

How can I figure out what's going on, and inspire my external monitor to awaken when summoned?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with my Lenovo (docking station). Workaround is to go to displays and change settings (e.g. activate Mirroring) and then the external monitors wake up, but then I have to rearrange all my windows.

Would like to know the root case of this.